# Oracle - Assign count value for a column based on another column in select query

Tags: oracle, select, group-by

Consider, I have the following in a select query:

```
ID   Flag
5     Y
5     Y
5     N
6     Y
6     Y
6     Y
6     N
```

I should be adding a new column **count** in the same select which counts the **number of 'Y' records** for the ID and assigns it to all. (Eg: ID=5 has 3 records. All of them should be assigned the count value as '2').

Output required in select query:

```
ID   Flag   count
5     Y      2
5     Y      2
5     N      2
6     Y      3
6     Y      3
6     Y      3
6     N      3
```

Comment: What does "ID Flag 5 Y 5 Y 5 N 6 Y 6 Y 6 Y 6 N" mean?

Comment: I am sorry. ID and Flag are two columns.. They got transposed as a single record..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select id, 
       flag, 
       count(case when flag = 'Y' then 1 end) over (partition by id) as "count"
from the_table
order by id;
```

The `case` expression will return null for flags with `N` and thus they will be ignored by the count() function

Comment: Even better, use a different name for the "count" column - a name that is not an Oracle (and SQL) keyword. More generally, use names that don't need to be defined in double-quotes. In this case, both `ct` and `cnt` are quite common.